# Eating parve food, which was cooked with dairy utensils, while fleishig

Tags: meat-and-milk

If I am fleishig, would I be able to eat bread that was warmed up in a dairy toaster?

Although this is a toaster, and at most the only thing put inside was parve bread whereas there would be no problem eating anything that came out of it in regard to ones milk/meat status, I was just wondering in general if Parve food is effected by the utensils it is cooked with.

Comment: Perhaps edit this to be less personal, and more specific. The answer is going to vary by minhag, and you're essentially asking for a personal ruling.